# Only showing values when scraping data using RegExp

Tags: regex, web-scraping, google-apps-script-editor

I am trying to scrape data from the following website: [Morningstar](https://www.morningstar.nl/nl/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F00000QIPC)
(https://www.morningstar.nl/nl/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F00000QIPC)

I want to scrape the `EUR 20,66`, but only display the '20,66'. I Use the following code:

```
function import1() {
  var  html, content = '';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.morningstar.nl/nl/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F00000QIPC"); 


  if (response) {
    html = response.getContentText();
    if (html) content = html.match(/<td class="line text">(.*?)<\/td>/)[1];
    Logger.log(content)
  }                                
   return content;

}
```

Displayed value is:

```
EUR 20,66
```

I tried to add `\d` to only show values:

```
if (html) content = html.match(/<td class="line text">(\d.*?)<\/td>/)[1];
```

but somehow it displays a different value:
`1,09%`

it doesn't seem to recognize the `20,66` as a value or something. I have tried different things where it would display `EUR20,` but never found something to remove the `EUR`
(I cannot replicate this scenario again sadly)

Any help solving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `/<td class="line text">\s*EUR\s+(\d[\d,]*)<\/td>/`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Have you considered using an HTML parser instead?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes this solves the problem thank you!, could you help me understand exactly what the /s*EUR and s+(\d) works?

Comment: @MLarionov , I am unsure how this would works exactly since I am new to all of this. You have a link to some examples or information about this so I can take a look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to match `EUR` and then a number after a variable amount of whitespace.

You may use

```
\s*EUR\s+(\d[\d,]*)
```

instead of `.*`.

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `EUR` - a literal text
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\d[\d,]*)` - Capturing group 1: a digit followed with 0 or more commas or digits.